# why Xcode treat two similar variable declaration differently, where first only display an warning and second display an warning + an error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to study swift access control. I have came up with the code below

```
private class Random{}

class Person {
    public var name: String = "John"
    public var aRandom = Random()
}
```

When I declared `public var name: String = "John"`, it only displayed an warning, saying `Declaring a public var for an internal class`.

When I declared `public var aRandom = Random()`, along with the warning, Xcode also displayed an error saying: `Property must be declared private because its type "Random" uses a private type.` . I was just wondering why does Xcode treat those two statements differently, where first only display an warning and second display an warning + an error?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*“A public variable cannot be defined as having an internal or private type, because the type might not be available everywhere that the public variable is used.”*

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

Private is meant to hide details or dependencies so that they can be changed in the future without effecting the user of that code.  Being marked private, `Random` is only visible to code **in that one file**.  That contradicts your intent to make a variable of that type public and visible outside the module or framework.

The reason why `name` does not also have an error is because its type is `String` which is a public type provided by the Swift standard library. It is globally available to all Swift code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comment. But I was just wondering why the first statement (i.e. public var name: String = "john") only has a warning?

Comment: Amended  my answer to discuss `name`.